# List files of folder page by page with LS command

Tags: linux, ls

I'm wonder if there is some way to list all files of a folder by ls, I know how to use ls for a folders which are small but if list of files doesn't match with the screen size what should I do? there is no scroll!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

pipe it into `more`:

```
ls -la | more
```

Then down arrow scrolls to the next line, spacebar jumps a page at a time

Comment: Use `| less` instead; as opposed to traditional "more", that will also allow you to scroll backwards, search forwards and backwards and so on. Press `h` for help, and remember that **less is more** (on some releases of some Linux distros, "more" may actually be "less" by another name, but don't rely on that).

Comment: When listing directories and using a *pager* such as `less`, you might want to try some of the options to make your browsing easier/more informative.  I'm partial to `/bin/ls -alFv --color=always | /usr/bin/less -iXRS`.  The `ls` options mean (respectively) show hidden files, show extended info, show punctuation to identify special files, sort numbers naturally, and show colors to identify file types.  The `less` options mean (respectively) ignore case when searching, don't clear screen when done, preserve colors from `ls`, and don't wrap long lines.

Answer (score 7):

`more` is good, [`less`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/less.htm) gives more scrolling options (up and down):

```
ls | less
```

If you want color:

```
ls --color=always | less -iXRS
```

Quit `less` as if it were `vi`, `:q`

Comment: `ls --color=always | less -iXRS ` keeps output log on the terminal